# 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new here and new to coding. I'm trying to run:

```
wd = wd.Chrome() 
wd.implicity_wait(10)
```

But I keep getting an error that reads

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

[Here's a picture of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuoEy.jpg)

Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you wanna do this instead :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe')
```

or in case you want to initiate with `ChromeOptions`, you can do it like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe', options = options)
```

You should give your `chromedriver.exe` file location in place of `C:\\Users\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe`

Answer (score 0):

first check google chrome version of your system by using this in URL chrome://version/

then download chrome driver from below mention website according to chrome version https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

then type this in pycharm or sublime text

```
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='C:/drivers/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Or

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```